# Como pasar datos de JSON a Entity Framework

Tags: javascript, html, json, entity-framework

Necesito pasar los datos desde una tabla HTML a la base de datos, los datos los estoy capturando con JS en un JSON pero no sé como pasar los datos desde el JSON a la base de datos.

Gracias

Comment: Cual lenguaje usa en el controladora?  C#?  Es MVC?

Comment: Si, C# y estoy usando MVC

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779043/post-json-array-to-mvc-controller Es en inglés, pero muestra exactamente lo que quiere hacer.